# SQL query returns only 1 row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a `visits` and a `ads` table.
I need every match from the `visits` table where the `visits.aid = ads.id` where the `ads.uid=1`. 
The actually query works, but I get everytime only 1 row from the `visits` table back and I need every selected row not just only one.

```
SELECT a.* FROM visits a INNER JOIN ads b ON a.aid = b.id WHERE b.uid = '1'
```

Comment: You need every row from the `visits` table and only the rows from `ads` table that match the `visits` table on `visits.aid = ads.id and ads.uid = 1`?

Comment: I need every match from the visits table where the visits.aid = ads.id where the ads.uid=1

Comment: Please update the question to include the actual values in both tables as well as the exact results you expect.

Comment: I just built out some temp tables and ran your query using SSMS, and your query is doing exactly what you want it to do.  More info would be helpful. Also, I noticed that you have b.uid = '1' and in your explaination you have ads.uid = 1.  Maybe it's a datatype issue.

Comment: Is this your schema? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/980db/1

Comment: The Query definitely selects multiple rows.

Comment: What happens if you do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ads WHERE uid = '1'`?

Comment: since you tagged this with PHP I'm assuming that you are trying to get the data via PHP. If that's the case then you've likely only fetched one row instead of all the rows. please post your associated PHP code.